# Error integrating GridDB with Docker: Failed to start GridDB container

Tags: docker, griddb

I'm trying to integrate GridDB with Docker using a Docker Compose configuration. However, I'm encountering an error while starting the GridDB container. The container fails to start, and I receive an error message indicating the issue with the Docker integration.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  griddb:
    image: griddb/griddb:latest
    container_name: griddb
    ports:
      - 10001:10001
      - 10010:10010
    environment:
      - GRIDDB_CLUSTER_NAME=griddb_cluster
      - GRIDDB_USERNAME=admin
      - GRIDDB_PASSWORD=admin
ERROR: Failed to start GridDB container.
       Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint griddb
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully integrate GridDB with Docker. Thank you.